# What is formula for repeating sequence $0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

can somebody help me with this? I was searching through the web and I did not find anything useful. What is the formula for the sequence:

**$0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...$**

or

**$0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...$**

I did find solution for $0,1,0,1$ or $1,0,1,0$ or $0,0,0,1$ etc.. But nothing close to this.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
Sorry everyone, I am quite new to this. It is a repeating infinite series. Also, I am looking for a more general solution so I can choose the number of zeros and ones - if $n = 3$ then I am looking for a repeating sequence:

**$0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, ...$**

**EDIT2:**
Example: I input let say "$k$" into a formula. I'll get $0$ or $1$ as an output. I use "$n$" as a variable for a function that will determine the repairing pattern e.g. If $n=2$ then the pattern is $0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1, ...$ and if $k=3$, then the output will be the third position, which is $1$ in this case.

Comment: These are finite series, or infinite?  If they are finite, listing the terms is a definition.

Comment: Your question does not make sense. The formula for a finite sequence $a_1,\ldots, a_n$ is that the $k$-th term is $a_k$. That's it.

Comment: It is infinite repeating series.

Comment: Do you know how it repeats?

Comment: Do you mean a formula in the sense that, when you input $n$, the output of the formula is the $n$th term?

Comment: I mean when I input let say "k" into a formula Ill get 0 or 1 as an output. I used "n" as a variable for a function that will determine the repairing pattern eg. n=2 than the pattern is 0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1, ... and if k=3 than output will be third position which is 1 in this case

Comment: Ah, now I see what you what. You should write that in the question...

Comment: $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_n=0$ and $a_k=1-a_{k-n}$ for $k >n$

Comment: These are sequences, not series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way:
$$
a_k=\frac{1\pm(-1)^{\left\lfloor\frac {k-1}n\right\rfloor}}2,
$$
where $n$ is the half-period of the sequence and with $\pm$ sign you can choose to start with $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Simplest? ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I think so.  For me it is simpler than write "$n$ zeros and $n$ ones repeat in this order infinitely". :)

Comment: @user I think $$\frac{1+(-1)^{\lceil k/n\rceil}}{2}$$ is a bit more simpler.

Comment: I did a little bit of coding here: `out[i] = int(((1/2)*(1+(-1)**((i-1)/(4)))).real)` but when I print first few outputs I get: **0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, ...** am I missing something ? (also **i** is integer numbers from 0 to 30)

Comment: @jjagmath :)) Excellent. I don't know why I like floor more than ceiling. However if one starts with $a_0$ the situation changes!

Comment: @SomeGuy You don't think that is simple?

Comment: @Simen Is it FORTRAN?

Comment: @user this is actually python :)

Comment: @Simen I have no experience with python. Did you check that the floor function works? (I do not see it in the code at all).

Comment: @jjagmath Seems like it could be simpler

Comment: Yeah this answer is clearest and simplest.

Comment: Ah! I did some research on ceil/floor functions in the math and I must say I am dumb today. This answer is super right, thank you a lot for the patience. Also my fixed code: `outs[i] = int(((1/2)*(1+(-1)**(math.ceil((k-1)/(n))))))`

Comment: I think the correct answer is @jjagmath. This video will show you how to derive that formula: youtu.be/jzrIwlHBykk

Comment: @user2298766 Both formulas are correct.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a formula based on another point of view.

Notice that

- $\operatorname{base_2}(0,\overline{01})=\frac 13$
- $\operatorname{base_2}(0,\overline{0011})=\frac 15$
- $\operatorname{base_2}(0,\overline{000111})=\frac 19$
- $\operatorname{base_2}(0,\overline{00001111})=\frac 1{17}$

It is not too complicated to verify that with $n$ zeroes and ones ($n$ being the half-period as in [user's](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4049163/399263) answer) then (where $x^n$ denotes the digits $\underbrace{xx\cdots x}_\text{n times}$)

$$\operatorname{base_2}(0,\overline{0^n1^n})=\frac 1{2^{n}+1}$$

So if we multiply by $2^k$ then the unit digit is either the $0$ or the $1$ at place $k$ in the binary development, giving the formula below:

$$a_k=\left\lfloor\frac{2^k}{2^n+1}\right\rfloor \bmod 2$$

*It is more interesting theoretically than as a practical way of calculating these numbers though...*

---

The formula based on powers of $(-1)^\alpha$ can be written with the floor function directly.

I think one efficient way of computing this sequence could be the following

$$a_k=\left\lfloor\frac kn\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac k{2n}\right\rfloor$$

The concept is simple, $\lfloor\frac x{2n}\rfloor$ has a period double than $\lfloor\frac x{n}\rfloor$, we multiply by $2$ so that both functions overlap on period $n$, their difference is then $0$, and on the remaining of the period it is $1$, giving birth to a $0^n1^n$ sequence of period $2n$.

Comment: Thank you also for the great answer! I will try this approach as well.

Comment: The second formula is shifted, it should be $$a_k=\left\lfloor\frac {k-1}{n}\right\rfloor-2\left\lfloor\frac {k-1}{2n}\right\rfloor$$

Answer (score 0):

If you accept boolean logic, then you can use following formula:

$$ a_k = \frac{(k \space AND \space 2)}{2} $$

Which will produce: 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 ....

To produce 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

You can use $$ a_k = \frac{(k \space AND \space 1)}{1} $$

In general it would be $$ a_k = \frac{(k \space AND \space c)}{c} $$ where c is the power of 2 which is it's main drawback.